# Silverlight 4 : Auto-display tooltips on out of bounds text

Tags: silverlight-4.0, tooltip

I have an item control wherein i display a list of string in rows and columns, the problem is that due to excess amount of text, the text gets cropped. So i wish to implement a tool-tip that can detect the excess text and display the complete text once i hover over the item or perhaps scroll the text once i hover onto it

PS: -i do not want to increase the width of the item control or the window
    -i do not want to wrap the text so it accommodates in a next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This guy](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2011/01/06/showing-tooltips-on-trimmed-textblock-silverlight.html) post a clever solution to this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, that was exactly what i needed, a very clever solution indeed...